# How to create Single Access Only records in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am having a problem with multiple users editing a single record at the same time and losing work when the other person saves the record with their own work. I would like to lock editing when a user is editing a record, and for some reason, records in NetSuite are not *single access only* by default. **How can we accomplish this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create your own locking mechanism.

- Create a custom table with record id and lock time and user, and expiration time.
- User event script that puts the record, time and user in the lock record.
- User event script that checks the lock record on load and redirects other user to view only screen with a message (I append a query parameter to the redirect)
- A client script keep-alive that pings the lock record with a new expiration time every X minutes while the user is still on the record.
- A user event script that clears the lock record.
- A clean up scheduled script that clears the lock record with expired keep alives.

Comment: Okay, this was something I was thinking about, but I worried about the clearing of the lock since a user could either click the Save button or simply just close the window. I'm not quite sure how to make that keep-alive script, but it sounds logical. Though I will say this all seems quite convoluted to implement.

Comment: Lots of steps but you are just touching a few fields. To avoid time issues make sure you store your expiration times as timestamps (`new Date().getTime()`) rather than as Netsuite datetimes.  The keep alive is just a standard client javascript. I'd probably use `setInterval` in the pageInit script.

Comment: Very nice.  Thank you!  Can you elaborate on the purpose of the redirect query parameter?

Comment: The query parameter on the redirect would need to be "read" by a client side script.This would pop a message when the record is loaded to the effect "This record is locked because it is currently being edited by another user...."

Comment: Gotcha, thanks.  I'd been considering how to do this myself and just hadn't thought of the keep-alive client script piece.

In your experience, do you have a recommended value for X (keep-alive time) and for a TTL before clearing out the lock in the scheduled script?

Do you delete the lock records?  I would imagine so, as the number of locks in the system would otherwise grow quite large and performance would degrade on searches.

Comment: X depends on your environment. In a call center app you'd expect the user is busy so I might take the record away in a minute. If the user's process once they are in front of the record is lengthy (e.g. they talk with their hands off the keyboard) then 10 minutes might be too short.

Comment: We have a Fulfillment script in 1.0 that pulls a Serial number from the custom record based on SKU and other parameters.
We are working on converting the script to 2.0. What I am unable to figure out is, if the script(say the above functionality is put into Map function for a MR script) will run on multiple queues/instances, does that mean that there is a potential chance that 2 instance might hit the same entry of the Custom record?
Is there a better way to accomplish this in 2.0? Also is there a wait I can impleme

Thx

Comment: You might want to expand your issue in another question. Once you are dealing with server side scripts it is a different set of issues

Comment: Thanks will post another question.